# How combine Repository Pattern and UoW

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-2.2

Im starting to prove EF-Core 2 and I read about Unit of Work and Repository pattern.Im trying to do a DB project Code First and I have 3 entities(Users,roducts and Providers), how I can apply repository pattern and unit of work in my project cause I dont know how to combine them in the same project,someone cna help me?

Comment: UoW and Repository pattern is redundant if you are using EF. The DbContext is already like a UoW and the DbSet is the repository. You are basically adding an abstraction on top of an abstraction.

Comment: @William Xifaras what if you want to abstract your business from ef so that one day you could change your ORM or even not use a data base and use something else, I mean abstracting ef core for you business logic is not a bad thing.

Comment: @MustafaSaeed How many times have you done that? I often hear that argument, but I can't remember being on a project where we changed our data access framework and I've been at this for years. Repository and UoW pattern get in the way of Entity Framework IMO. I'm not advocating for combining services/business logic with your data access code. Alternatives are CQS, CQRS, creating classes that encapuslate your EF operations and call them from a service layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a microsoft link explaning how to do it 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I see that it is for EF 4, this will also be usefull for EFCore 2? I mean, is the same way of do it in EF 4 and EF Core?

Comment: @RaudelCosta yes it is the same way